# Can we stop a groupview not to show its childList when touched on it (For some specific cases)

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my project, Expandable list view is common for all logins, but in new update, based on role of login user, i want to stop showing children of certain groupviews. I managed to put an "Access Denied" dialog, but I cannot stop, the expansion of groupview or showing child view. Is there a way for that?

I tried to pass role to the adapter of the expandableListAdapter class and write some cases in getChildView like if (groupPosition==1 && role == 1) I inflated an empty layout. This way I cannot prevent expansion, the child view is still being shown but it is empty and on clicking of that, it is throwing null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for that, I returned the child count for my specific cases 0

```
@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.e("getChildrenCount", "getChildrenCount");

        if ((this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) == null)
                || (roleId.equalsIgnoreCase("2") && groupPosition!=1)
                || (roleId.equalsIgnoreCase("3") && groupPosition!=2)
                || (roleId.equalsIgnoreCase("5") && groupPosition!=4)   )
            return 0;
        else
            return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }
```

This worked for me
Thanks